# Open-ended SVG import

Tags: import, svg

I am trying to import a SVG from Illustrator. This SVG is simply an unstroked curve. This curve is open-ended: it does not form a closed "loop". Rather, it is more of a piece of rope.

When I try to import it into Blender, it connects both ends of the rope to form something messy. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

Try going into the curve properties and under *Active Spline*, uncheck the "Cyclic" box:

[image: Cyclic]